# Adding properties to Javascript object at run time

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, invokescript

Let's say I have this function in javascript

```
    function EstablishUserSession(params) {
        gecResult = "noResult";            
        params["callbackOnSuccess"] = Success;
        params["callbackOnException"] = Exception;
        controller.establishUserSessionIAPI(params);
        return "requestSent";
    }
```

params is an object passed in through HtmlDocument.InvokeScript.. Looks like this

```
{ iapiUri: "dfdfdsf", language: "en", partnerUsername: "ddddd", integrationPartnerId: 1, cleartextPassword: "dddd"}
```

The above works fine in Chrome and FFox. Does not work in IE8. I get Object doesn't support property or method.

```
    function EstablishUserSession(params) {
        gecResult = "noResult";
        jQuery.extend(params, { callbackOnSuccess: Success, callbackOnException: Exception });
        controller.establishUserSessionIAPI(params);
        return "requestSent";
    }
```

Then I changed to Jquery.extend... works fine in Chrome and FFox. Does not work in IE8.

Does anyone out there know how to correctly extend an object to add properties as above!

note: Success and Exception are just callbacks

Comment: Did you try iterating over the new object adding each key:value to the old object 'manually' ?

Comment: That will be my last resort... I want this to be a generic framework. These param objects can get very large...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a new copy of the object..

```
var newParams = $.extend({ newProp : value}, oldParams);
```

Comment: well that works in Chrome again... now to try IE.. fingers crossed